# Environment Modules source file

Tags: environment-variables, environment-modules

Hello I'm using the project "Environment Modules" in a linux cluster to ease the usage of softs for the users.

Some of my softwares don't only rely on environment variables but as well needs that some files be sourced. How can I source a file from a modulefiles? Or the idea is to "translate" the content of the file to be sourced in a modulefiles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since version 4.6 you've got two [possibilities](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/source-script-in-modulefile.html):

- `source-sh`: eg. in your modulefile `source-sh bash some-script.sh`
- `sh-to-mod`: for preparing your modulefile: `module sh-to-mod some-script.sh > modulefile`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/modules/wiki/FAQ/#i-want-the-modulefile-to-source-some-rc-script-that-came-with-some-application), it's a bad idea because it's not possible to unload the module later.

They recommend to create a modulefile instead:

```
env | sort > envbefore
. somescript
env | sort > envafter
diff envbefore envafter
```